# receive and send data throught socket in C

Tags: c, string, sockets, asn.1

I want to receive a string, make a reverse and resend it through a socket. The string is encoded with ASN.1.

```
recv( to_server_socket, &buffer2, sizeof( buffer2 ), MSG_WAITALL );
ber_decode(0, &asn_DEF_Message02, (void**) &message2, buffer2, sizeof buffer2);
xer_fprint(stdout, &asn_DEF_Message02, message2);
printf( "Server --> %d\n", message2->number );  
char* serverString = message2->string.buf;
    int byte_count = message2->string.size;
    char reverseString[50];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i < byte_count; ++i)
    {
      char c = serverString[i];
      if(c=='\0')
      {
        reverseString[i] = '\0';
        break;
      }
      else if(c>=65 && c<=90)
        reverseString[i] = c+32;
      else if(c>=97 && c<=122)
        reverseString[i] = c-32;
      else
        reverseString[i] = c;
    }
    printf("String to send: %s\n", reverseString);
```

I receive the number and the string correctly but when I make the conversion I get some extra caracters like in this output

```
<Message02>
    <number>35</number>
    <string>Dh3i5KhQNM5OgNh6O</string>
</Message02>
Server --> 35
String to send: dH3I5kHqnm5oGnH6oڹQ
msg3_buf: 
30 16 13 14 64 48 33 49 35 6b 48 71 6e 6d 35 6f 47 6e 48 36 6f ffffffda ffffffb9 51 00 00 <Message03>
    <string>dH3I5kHqnm5oGnH6oڹQ</string>
</Message03>
```

Comment: What is the Message02 ASN.1 definition? What are you using to represent a string? what is msg3_buf? I cannot decode what you print..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, putting together all the information you have in different questions (e.g. [receive and reverse a string asn.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611106/receive-and-reverse-a-string-asn1)) I've reproduced your problem.

First the solution to the problem: You are not null terminating the reverseString. That's why when you try to print there's garbage after it. Solution is simply to add after the for loop

```
reverseString[i]='\0';
```

... I'm not 100% sure that the received string is null terminated (it might, they are probably nice and do it for you)... but even if that's the case, the size field does not include the end-of-string '\0'

Now, a bit of background. Your definition (according to the question cited above) is:

```
Message02 ::= SEQUENCE {
    number INTEGER, -- incremented integer
    string PrintableString (SIZE (10..20)) -- random string
}
```

In ASN.1 strings there's no need for a null-termination convention for strings, since length of values is always well defined in the Tag-Length-Value structure. In fact, the online compiler you are using handles PrintableString as OCTET STRING, which can give you a hint that everything is being treated as a raw buffer.

So, for example if you sent number=100 and string="Hello World" you will get in the DER encoding:

```
30 10 // 0x30 = SEQUENCE, 0x10 = Length 16
   02 01 64  // 0x02 = INTEGER, 0x01 = Lenght 1, 0x64= Value 100
   13 0b 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 // 0x13 = PrintableString 0x0b= Length 11, value= "Hello World"
```

I haven't used this compiler for any serious stuff (I've only used to try to reproduce the problem), si I cannot say what is the recommended best practice for OCTETSTRINGS or PrintableStrings, but be wary of char buffer....

Finally, my complete program (instead of sending it through a socket, I'm encoding to a buffer and decoding from the same buffer)

```
#include "Message02.h"
#include <string.h>


#define BUFFERSIZE 100

int main() {
    Message02_t *message1;
    char buffer2[BUFFERSIZE];
    int ival=100;
    char *sval="Hello World";

    message1 = calloc(1, sizeof(Message02_t));
    message1->number = 100;
    message1->string.buf = sval;
    message1->string.size = strlen(sval);
    der_encode_to_buffer(&asn_DEF_Message02, message1, buffer2, BUFFERSIZE);

    //receive Message02
    Message02_t *message2 = 0;
    message2 = calloc(1, sizeof(Message02_t));
    //recv( to_server_socket, &buffer2, sizeof( buffer2 ), MSG_WAITALL );
    ber_decode(0, &asn_DEF_Message02, (void**) &message2, buffer2, sizeof buffer2);
    xer_fprint(stdout, &asn_DEF_Message02, message2);
    printf( "received number %d\n", message2->number );
    printf( "received String %s\n", message2->string.buf );
    printf( "received String size %d\n", message2->string.size );

    int j;
    for(j=0;j<BUFFERSIZE;j++) {
       printf("%02x",buffer2[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    char* serverString = message2->string.buf;
    int byte_count = message2->string.size;
    char reverseString[50];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i < byte_count; ++i)
    {
      char c = serverString[i];
      if(c=='\0')
      {
        reverseString[i] = '\0';
        break;
      }
      else if(c>=65 && c<=90)
        reverseString[i] = c+32;
      else if(c>=97 && c<=122)
        reverseString[i] = c-32;
      else
        reverseString[i] = c;
    }
    reverseString[i]='\0'; /* <=== THIS IS THE FIX */
    printf("String to send: %s\n", reverseString);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is likely faulty:

```
int byte_count = message2->string.size;
```

The string.size likely isn't what you expect. This is probably the storage size of the buffer, and not the length of the string inside the buffer.

This is why you see `ffffffda` etc. (they are negative numbers, you're subtracting from 0, most likely).

Comment: Actually, it's probably the size of the ASN.1 string object which would be expected to be two more than the length of the string data (one type byte, one length byte).

Comment: I tried int byte_count = sizeof( serverString ) and int byte_count = strlen( serverString ) but still the same problem :/

Comment: I feel these answer is wrong... we need more information from the OP... At least the ASN.1 definition to see what he's trying to encode... The first thing is what is being used to represent a string... could be an IA5String, but I'm not sure how well that will be represented in this library...

Comment: @user3235881 I've added my own answer. This answer is wrong: size does contain the size of the value received, e.g. If you sent "Hello World" it will contain 11. So it is not the storage size of the buffer and it is not the size of the TLV (not two more)... ASN.1 strings are not null terminated... so the the length of the buffer will not contain any null character... and that's precisely what the OP is missing.

Comment: Regarding "ASN.1 strings are not null-terminated". ASN.1 doesn't specify what the "concrete syntax" looks like, which is what you have when you have the message in a language structure. It only specifies the "logical syntax" (the ASN.1 language) and the "transfer syntax" (the mappings between the ASN.1 language and a transfer encoding such as BER. PER or a number of others.

Thus, the concept of whether or not a string is null-terminated in the structure is a implementation matter for the ASN.1 compiler (abstract syntax <-> concrete syntax) 

Just wanted to add a bit more clarity.